# How to prevent a code block in a list item from making a gap between other list items?

Tags: markdown

How to prevent a code block of a list item from making a gap between the next list item and the list item after it or, for the GitHub flavor of markdown, before the item containing the code block?

```
* list item 1 
* list item 2
* list item 3

        code block line
        code block line

* list item 4
* list item 5
* list item 6
```

Which on Stack Overflow renders into:

- list item 1
- list item 2
- list item 3

  ```
  code block line
  code block line
  ```
- list item 4
- list item 5
- list item 6

A gap can be seen between list item 4 and list item 5.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the gap is caused by list item 4 being wrapped in `<p>` (paragraph) tags. This seems to fix it:

```
* list item 1 
* list item 2
* list item 3

        code block line
        code block line
* list item 4
* list item 5
* list item 6
```

Because there's no empty line before list item 4, it's not placed in a separate paragraph.

- list item 1
- list item 2
- list item 3

  ```
  code block line
  code block line
  ```
- list item 4
- list item 5
- list item 6

Comment: Doesn't work for GitHub markdown, still creates a gap http://jbt.github.io/markdown-editor/#01LIySwuUcgsSc1VMFTg0kLiGqHwjLm4FKAgOT8lVSEpJz85Gyifl4pTHFm7CQrPFIVnBgA=

Comment: But what about the gap between item 2 and item 3? The whole thing just looks bad.

Comment: @DesmondHume That's github's CSS. The leading space is caused by `3px` of padding on the left for `<code>` elements. The gap is caused by `1em` of vertical margin on `<p>` elements (both above and below); it doesn't affect the other list items because the margin is explicitly disabled if the `<p>` is the last thing in a list element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using '```', which denotes a code-block in markdown: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code

````
*  list item 1 
*  list item 2
*  list item 3
```
   code block line
   code block line
```
*  list item 4
*  list item 5
*  list item 6
````

It seems SO and Github styles Markdown differently, but the editor you referenced produces the desired result.